# How to set 1st date and last date of the month on Bootstrap date?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date-picker on  HTML form

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,

    });


});
```

Now i have two date fields on my form called start-date and end-date. I want to set start-date to be the 1st day of the month and end -date to be the last date of the month . Is it possible to set it on Bootstrap date-picker ? sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried? please mention your code here. You want the datepickers to be fixed on 1st & last days of every month?

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateToday = new Date();
 var fromDate = (dateToday.getMonth() + 1) + "/01/" +    dateToday.getFullYear()
 var toDate = (dateToday.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateToday.getDate() + "/" + dateToday.getFullYear()
```

see more of my answer here. [JQuery DatePicker on ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687644/jquery-datepicker-on-asp-net/27687884#27687884)

or this

```
var month = 0; // January
var d = new Date(2008, month + 1, 0);
alert(d); // last day in January
```

from [Calculate last day of month in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript)